# Why is a UITabBar considered Modal?

Tags: iphone, modal-dialog, uitabbar

Reading the Apple documentation on the UITabBar states,

> The most common use of a tab bar is to
>   implement a modal interface where
>   tapping an item changes the selection.

With my definition of Modal being:

> A modal view is one that has to be
>   dismissed before you can do anything
>   else.

But that's not always the use case. I could be interacting with the content view of the UITabBar's first item/button, and that could allow me to reach another view.

OR, I could select another item/button from the UITabBar and reach yet another view.

So how is that considered Modal? (Or is my use case not Modal, and they are just saying, in general, its used Modally?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "modal" here means different "[mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28computer_interface%29)s".

Comment: Well it says Modal in the documentation. I thought Modal != Modes.